# Can't copy from remote to local

Tags: ssh, pscp

I am trying to copy from remote ubuntu machine to local windows:

```
pscp name@example.com:/home/www/file c:\xampp\htdocs
```

Instead of getting a copy on local i get c:xampphtdocs file created on a remote.

I was refering to this http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219485/issue-with-character-in-bash-script-over-ssh/219639#219639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pscp` doesn't handle well the colons in your path and it thinks that `c` is remote server. If you use relative path like this, it should work for you:

```
c:\
pscp name@example.com:/home/www/file \xampp\htdocs
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am not sure how to use relative path. i tried something like `c:\ pscp name@example.com:/home/www/file \xampp\htdocs`but there is no such command

Comment: these are two lines, two different commands. The first is to make sure you are on the correct drive. The other should invoke the `pscp`. If you are in `C:\`, you can use only the second row.